# Core Data: Fetched attributes with joined tables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, fetched-property

I have a Host which has a many-to-many relationship with services. The relation is through a join table "hostServices". I would like to fetch te services related to a Host via a "fetched property". But how do I define the predicate?

I now did something like 'ANY hostServices.host.name == "$FETCH_SOURCE.name"' and I have tried 'ANY hostServices.host == "$FETCH_SOURCE"'.

But that didn't work. Does anyone know how I could fetch the services?

Thanks in advance!

[My data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po2OX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
host == $FETCH_SOURCE
```

Comment: Ow, wait. I made it an expression. But then I get: keypath host not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Service id=5>'

Comment: This doesn't work: ANY hostServices.host.name == "$FETCH_SOURCE.name"
But this does: ANY hostServices.host.name == "bimbo.ping.uio.no"

Should I do something with FETCH_SOURCE?

Comment: Have you specified the Host entity with an inverse relationship on the HostService entity? Perhaps you could post your data model?

Comment: Hi Chris, I misread your answer. I had to ditch the quotes. So your suggestion worked perfectly! Thanks! This was the correct setting: http://i.imgur.com/pLSuO.png